# sync event not issued when model is destroyed - Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The model collection is not issuing a 'sync' event when a model is destroyed. the documentation [seems to say the opposite](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy). here is my code snippet:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ id: 1, val: "foo" });
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: MyModel, url: '/api/models' });

var myCollection = new MyCollection();

myCollection.on('sync', function () { console.log('synced!'); });
myCollection.on('remove', function () { console.log('removed!'); });

myCollection.fetch(); // => outputs synced!

    // .. wait for collection to load

myCollection.at(0).destroy(); // => outputs removed! but *NOT* synced!
```

If I understand well, the doc says the 'destroy' event should bubble up to the collection and issue a 'sync' event. Should the collection in the code above issue a 'sync' event or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'sync' event is triggered on the destroyed object after being removed from the collection.  This is why the collection doesn't fire a 'sync' event. The collection relays the 'destroy' event though.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: 'sync' is triggered on the model after it is removed from the collection, even if `wait:true` option is used.

Here is the code from Backbone, which triggers the model events on the collection.

```
// Internal method called every time a model in the set fires an event.
// Sets need to update their indexes when models change ids. All other
// events simply proxy through. "add" and "remove" events that originate
// in other collections are ignored.
_onModelEvent: function(event, model, collection, options) {
  if ((event === 'add' || event === 'remove') && collection !== this) return;
  if (event === 'destroy') this.remove(model, options);
  if (model && event === 'change:' + model.idAttribute) {
    delete this._byId[model.previous(model.idAttribute)];
    if (model.id != null) this._byId[model.id] = model;
  }
  this.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

Your problem is most likely because the 'sync' event is not triggered on the model (and then triggered on the collection) due to an error in during the sync.

From the Backbone source, you can see that 'sync' is triggered when the request succeeds, so maybe you can debug that and see if the success callback in `sync` is hit?

```
var success = options.success;
    options.success = function(resp) {
      if (success) success(model, resp, options);
      model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);  // breakpoint here.
    };
```

Can you put a breakpoint in there and see if the event is triggered?  I assume it will not hit this line.

Also try using an error callback:

```
myCollection.at(0).destroy({
    error: function(model, xhr, options){
        console.log(model);  // this will probably get hit
    }
});
```

Comment: In the code above I  listening to sync on the collection, not the model: it is NOT triggered. Remove event IS triggered. My question is not about those events. It is about sync event not being triggered on collection. Please read my code and question.

Comment: I did read it. When 'sync' is  triggered on the model, `_onModelEvent` in the collection triggers the same event on the collection.  Put the breakpoint I suggested and see if that is hit, you might have an error in the sync, which would cause your problem.

Comment: When you destroy a model, unless you pass `wait:true` it optimistically removes it from the collection.  This is why you would get the 'remove' event but not the 'sync' event.  The sync is not successful.

Comment: Added the error handler and put a breakpoint as advised: it's not hit. I stepped in the bb code and the success callback is actually called. Added a listener on 'sync' for the destroyed object and it is actually fired correctly :-/ only sync on collection is not fired.

Comment: I think sync is triggered on the object *after* being removed from the collection, hence the problem :)

Comment: Yes... That is it.  What were you planning to do on 'sync' event from the collection?  Maybe it is better to explicitly listen for 'destroy' or 'remove' instead.

Comment: Indeed, updated my code to listen to destroy. I am trying to keep model changes with latest version fetched from server. I am missing this feature in bbonejs